# Consider three six-sided dice, and let random variable Y = the value of the face for each.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

The probability mass function is given by the following table. I am having trouble trying to solve this mathematically.

Comment: You can compute the pmf exactly or simulate using the Central Limit Theorem. Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: Perhaps see first "Related" link in right margin for analytic solution of PMF. Simulation and some theory in my extended comment/answer.

Comment: The word "simulated" seems to imply that the purpose of this exercise is _not_ to solve it "mathematically." An answer below shows how to use the software package R to simulate the experiment. Did the source you got this problem from also provide a statistical/probability software package you can use?

Comment: As @awkward has pointed out, the die is not fair, so finding $E(S)$ and $Var(S)$ to be nontrivial, thus maybe part of exercise is to do at least that much 'math'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment:** In order to give you a general idea how 
such a simulation can be done, I am showing R code for
a million 3-dice experiments, along with some remarks.
The R function `sample(1:6, 3, rep=T)` randomly 'throws' 3 fair dice,

```
set.seed(1234)     # for reproducibility
m = 10^6;  n = 3
x = replicate( m, sum(sample(1:6, 3, rep=T)) )

mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 10.49926       # aprx E(X) = 3(3.5) = 10.5
2*sd(x)/sqrt(m)
[1] 0.005916101    # aprx 95% margin of sim error for E(X)

[1] 8.750062       # aprx V(X) = ??

mean(x>2 & x<13)
[1] 0.7407         # aprx P(2 < X < 13)
2*sd(x>2 & x<13)/sqrt(m)
[1] 0.0008765015   # aprx 95% margin of sim for this peobability
```

*Notes:* Of course simulated values are only estimates. But there are ways to assess accuracy.

- It is easy to find the exact mean and variance for one die
  by analytic means, and thus to find exact values for $E(X)$ and $V(X).$
  By the Law of Large Numbers, sample means of a million values should
  be good approximations of respective population values.
- Similarly for
  $P(2 <X< 13).$ [What is the normal approximation of this probability?
- By the Central 
  Limit Theorem you can get 95% margins of simulation error for the mean and the probability above.

The histogram is a bit tricky because you want one bin for each
possible value 3 through 18 (controlled here by the `br` parameter).

```
hdr = "Simulated Dist'n: Total on 3 Faie Dice"
hist(x, prob=T, br=(2:18)+.5, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
```

[image]

With a million iterations, you can manipulate results of `table` to get
(very likely) numerators of $6^3$ in the PMF.

```
round(6^3*table(x)/m)
x
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18   # values of X
 1  3  6 10 15 21 25 27 27 25 21 15 10  6  3  1   # PMF numerators
```

For example, it is easy to see that $P(X = 3) = 1/216.$

**Addendum:** Your die is unfair, The R `sample` function can handle that. 
Parts of the simulation are modified for your unfair die as follows:

```
set.seed(509)
m = 10^6;  n = 3;  pr = c(.35,.30, .25, .05, .03, .02)
x = replicate( m, sum(sample(1:6, 3, rep=T, prob=pr)) )
mean(x)
[1] 6.512189       # aprx E(X) = 6.51
2*sd(x)/sqrt(m)
[1] 0.004042752    # aprx 96% margin of sim error 
mu = sum((1:6)*pr);  mu.s = 3*mu;  mu.s
[1] 6.51           # exact E(X)

hdr = "Simulated Dist'n: Total on 3 Unfaie Dice"
hist(x, prob=T, br=(2:18)+.5, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
```

[image]

Comment: Good illustration, but it should be mentioned that the simulation here is for fair dice, whereas the dice in the OP are biased.

Comment: @awkward. Right. Will post addendum, Now, if possible. Recovering from minor hand surgery, so I'm slowly hunting and pecking.

Comment: Thank you so much